# Invalid JSON String Parsing

Tags: javascript, json

It's really early east coast time, and I can't for the life of me see why this JSON string is invalid.. Does anyone else see anything? *(I've been looking at this for about 30 minutes now doing the old head meet desk routine)*

```
{
    'Subsidiaries': [{
        'SubsidiaryID': '4',
        'Level': 'Division'
     }, 
     {
        'SubsidiaryID': '3',
        'Level': 'Subsidiary'
     }]
}
```

Comment: I find it often a good sleep solves many problems...

Comment: If you have a comment about voting, please post it as a comment instead of adding it to the question.

Comment: Why all the downvotes...this was a serious question that I couldn't see the answer too? It may be a simple question, but it's still a well formed question with code.

Comment: Everyone who downvotes questions like this are the reason new people are sometimes afraid to use stack overflow. Yes it's simple, but I didn't do any of the standard downvote things like (give me code, way off topic, or no effort)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your current parser does not offer enough information, you can use a JSON validator to find out the exact details. There're even on-line ones like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/):

> ```
> Error: Parse error on line 1:
> { 'Subsidiaries': [{  
> --^
> Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
> ```

So it's clear that `'Subsidiaries'` is not a valid **string** and the validator points you the exact character that's invalid. You have the wrong quotes (remember that JSON is not JavaScript).

Comment: Dammit... single quotes vs doule quotes.. I knew it was something stupid I wasn't seeing. Thanks so much! The old second pair of eyes thing always helps for these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Both keys and strings in JSON must be wrapped in double quotes (`"`), in your example they are wrapped with single quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the issue is with the single quote. just replace it with double quotes. try below json

```
{
"Subsidiaries": [
    {
        "SubsidiaryID": "4",
        "Level": "Division"
    },
    {
        "SubsidiaryID": "3",
        "Level": "Subsidiary"
    }
]}
```